# How to get the checked items string in a CheckListBox

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

```
foreach (var item in clbSymptoms.CheckedItems)
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@fName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtFName.Text.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + txtFName.Text.Substring(1);
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@MName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtMName.Text.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + txtMName.Text.Substring(1);
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@lName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtLName.Text.ToUpper();
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@patientAge", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtAge.Text;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@purok", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = cbPurok.Text;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@caseClass", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = cbClass.Text;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@q1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = cbQuestion1.Checked;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@q2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = cbQuestion2.Checked;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@symptoms", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = item.ToString();
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

[image]

I want the symptoms to have their own cell but the name and other things to be a single cell only.

Comment: What if you have more than one checked item?  Do you need all the checked items into a single string?  Is there a separator, like a comma between the items?

Comment: What's the expecation here? If there are multiple items checked, what should be the outcome?

Comment: @LarsTech I was thinking seperating the checked items with single lines so I won't need a comma

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i want all the checkeditems in a single string

Comment: Example `HeadacheCoughColdFever` like this?

Comment: `separating the checked items with single lines` You need to loop over the CheckedItems collection and perform a new Insert call for every item, if I understand your request.  Your comment goes against your other comment `I want all the checkeditems in a single string`.  So we still don't know what you want to do here.

Comment: each symptom in a single line headache\ncough\nfever...

Comment: @LarsTech i meant single lines in a single string. I'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: With: `clbSymptoms.CheckedItems` you have the checked items. The rest depends on what you need to do. You could use a foreach: 
 `foreach (var item in clbSymptoms.CheckedItems)
{  
 //DO what you need to do
} `

Comment: `var s = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, clbSymptoms.CheckedItems.Cast<string>().ToArray());`  Not a good way to save data in a database, by the way.  Every checked item should have it's own row in your symptoms table.

Comment: @LarsTech you are probably right, i don't what I was trying to do. _Every checked item should have it's own row in your symptoms table_. Please show me.

Comment: You didn't show enough code, but start the loop before your cmd declaration: `foreach(var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems) {...}`

Comment: @LarsTech I updated my question. I'm really new to programming so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through your checked items like this:

```
foreach(var item in clbSymptoms.CheckedItems)
{
  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
  {
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@fName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtFName.Text.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + txtFName.Text.Substring(1);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtMName.Text.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + txtMName.Text.Substring(1);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@lName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtLName.Text.ToUpper();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@patientAge", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtAge.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@purok", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = cbPurok.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@caseClass", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = cbClass.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@questionnaire", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "(1)" + cbQuestion1.Checked + " " + "(2)" + cbQuestion2.Checked;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@symptoms", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = item.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

Comment: when i select more that one symptom every symptom has it's own cell but the names and patient age also repeats. I tried fixing it myself but I cannot figure it out

Comment: i updated my question again, please help me out

Comment: @JianCeleste I can only help so much.  You should have a Symptoms table that just records the symptom and the key to the question or patient, I guess.  I don't know enough about your project.  You need to learn how to make all these tables relate to each other.